# Pivot Query that Puts the rows into different columns depending on the value of a column

Tags: sql-server, select, pivot-table

There are devices that go through different types of inspection by different people. My table has DeviceID, InspectID, Date, and PersosnID for these info. Each device can go through multiple types of inspection and therefore there will be multiple rows in the table for that device.

```
    DeviceID     InspectID           Date                PersonID
    1            10                  1/1/2014            100
    1            20                  2/2/2014            200 
    2            10                  3/3/2014            300
    2            30                  4/4/2014            400
```

I am looking for the pivot query that creates a view of table where there is only one row per device and all types of inspection are shown in the columns. Let say I know in advance that InspectIDs are only 10, 20 and 30.

```
DeviceID  Date10   PersonID10 Date20   PersonID20 Date30   PersonID30
1         1/1/2014 100        2/2/2014 200        NULL     NULL                            
2         3/3/2014 300        NULL     NULL       4/4/2014 400
```

I think this can be done with a pivot query but I am very new to pivots. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT DeviceID,'Date'+CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)) InspectID,[DATE],
    'Person'+ CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)) PersonId,PersonId PERSONNO
    FROM YourTable WHERE DeviceID=1
                UNION ALL
    SELECT DeviceID,'Date'+CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)) InspectID,[DATE],
    'Person'+ CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)),PersonId PERSONNO
    FROM YourTable WHERE DeviceID=2
)
SELECT DeviceID,
MIN(CASE WHEN InspectID ='Date10' THEN [DATE] END) Date10,
MIN(CASE WHEN PersonId ='Person10' THEN PERSONNO END) PersonId10, 
MIN(CASE WHEN InspectID ='Date20' THEN [DATE] END) Date20, 
MIN(CASE WHEN PersonId ='Person20' THEN PERSONNO END) PersonId20,
MIN(CASE WHEN InspectID ='Date30' THEN [DATE] END) Date30,  
MIN(CASE WHEN PersonId ='Person30' THEN PERSONNO END) PersonId30    
FROM CTE1
GROUP BY DeviceID
```

Here is the ?SQLFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fe3b/2

Comment: But what if I have 100000 Devices, you are suggesting to UNION 100000 times???!!!

Comment: I had answered for your given table. UNION doen't reflect the number of devices, but effects the Date. Here you need to do it for Dynamic date. Teh following query will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

> Create a temperory table from your table

```
SELECT * INTO #TTT FROM 
(
    SELECT DeviceID,'Date'+CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)) InspectID,[DATE],
    'Person'+ CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)) PersonId,PersonId PERSONNO
    FROM #YourTable WHERE DeviceID=1
                UNION ALL
    SELECT DeviceID,'Date'+CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)) InspectID,[DATE],
    'Person'+ CAST(InspectID AS VARCHAR(5)),PersonId PERSONNO
    FROM #YourTable WHERE DeviceID=2
)TAB
```

> Now Pivot for InspectId

```
DECLARE @colsL NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @colsL = COALESCE (@colsL + ',[' + CAST(INSPECTID AS VARCHAR) + ']', '[' + CAST(INSPECTID AS VARCHAR) + ']')
FROM  #TTT 
group by INSPECTID
ORDER BY INSPECTID


DECLARE @FQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @FQuery =   '
                select * INTO NEW  from  
                (
                    select DEVICEID,INSPECTID,[DATE] from #TTT
                ) as p
                PIVOT
                ( 
                    MIN([DATE]) FOR  INSPECTID IN ('+@colsL+')   
                ) AS PT          
                '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @FQuery
```

> Now, pivot for PersonId and join with DeviceId from from previous
>   Pivotted table

```
DECLARE @colsL2 NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @colsL2 = COALESCE (@colsL2 + ',[' + CAST(PERSONID AS VARCHAR) + ']', '[' + CAST(PERSONID AS VARCHAR) + ']')
FROM  #TTT
group by PERSONID
ORDER BY PERSONID


DECLARE @FQuery2 NVARCHAR(MAX) --@colsL get the INSPECTID columns 
SET @FQuery2 =  '    
                select PT.*,'+@colsL+'
                FROM  
                (
                    select DEVICEID,PERSONID,PERSONNO from #TTT
                ) as p
                PIVOT
                ( 
                    MIN(PERSONNO) FOR  PERSONID IN ('+@colsL2+')   
                ) AS PT   
                JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT * FROM NEW
                )AS N 
                ON PT.DEVICEID=N.DEVICEID      
                '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @FQuery2
```

> Now you have the result, but you have to apply some other Logic to
>   order the columns(becz the columns are dynamic). You can do it
>   front-end too by taking the column as (4,1),(5,2),(6,3) etc etc